# Lots of temp tables: civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_*

Tags: core

On 5.6.0 (and prior), Civi seems to constantly be creating these civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_* temp tables and does not drop them. I'm seeing these keep growing in our database and have to keep dropping them manually.  What causes these tables to show up and why isn't it cleaning up after itself?

Comment: I am seeing this as well with a few of our clients. Wondering if anyone else is.

Comment: @guyiac, not sure this is the answer, but I noticed that as of our upgrade to 5.13, I'm no longer seeing all these temp tables being created. You might want to try that and see. We happened to also upgrade our OS plus php/mysql around the same time, but I'm guessing those would not have affected this, it must have been a Civi issue that was resolved in a later version than 5.6. At least, for a bit now (since 5.13.4 came out), I haven't seen the tables.